# WinUI3: display dialog at startup from main window?

Tags: modal-dialog, winui-3, winui

I'm getting started with WinUI3. Having no previous experience with UWP or WPF or even much C#, it's tough going.

Today's question is how to display a simple dialog at startup. Consider that we start with a simple app, as generated by Visual Studio. We have a `MainWindow` class defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs and its associated XAML (MainWindow.xaml). I believe the class is called a code-behind class.

So I want to do something as simple as display a dialog when the (desktop) app runs. It looks as though a `ContentDialog` is the way to go. But how to display it? As I understand it, I'm going to need to set the XamlRoot, so naively I tried this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DisplayDialog();
}

private async void DisplayDialog()
{
    var dlg = new ContentDialog();
    dlg.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot; // <-- set the XAML root here, but it's null
    dlg.Content = "Hello World";
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

This doesn't work. When called, the main window's XAML root is null and trying to show the dialog throws an exception:

[image]

How do I detect when it's ok to use the main window's XAML root? [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4242) seems to hint at an `OnLoaded` event, but I can't find anything about OnLoaded events in WinUI. Did I miss something?

This only way I can get this to work is to hook into the window's button and respond to its Loaded event, i.e.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myButton.Loaded += MyButton_Loaded; // <-- hack
}

private void MyButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayDialog();
}

private async void DisplayDialog()
{
    var dlg = new ContentDialog();
    dlg.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot; // <-- this is non-null now!
    dlg.Content = "Hello World";
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

But this feels really dirty. I don't even know if it's guaranteed that the XamlRoot will be non-null just because a button has loaded. And anyway, latching onto the button load seems very much like a hack. It relies on there being a button for one thing!

**So how should I achieve the simple task of putting a dialog on the screen when all I have is the main window?**

All help very gratefully received. Please try to make any answers as newbie-friendly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `MainWindow` has no `Loaded` events. What you can do is to work with a `Page` instead. So basically use the `MainWindow` as a "Window" and use `Pages` for your contents.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new ContentDialog();
        dlg.XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot;
        dlg.Content = "Hello World";
        await dlg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ContentDialogs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ContentDialogs"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <local:MainPage />

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll give that a try. Coming from a Win32/MFC C++ background, this is all takes some getting used to! If you know of any really good online resources or books that explain the fundamentals, then do let me know.

Comment: You can find a few WinUI 3 related books. I haven't read them by they have good ratings. I'd also recommend these 2 blogs [XAML Brewer](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/) and [Nick's .NET Travels](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/). I also post videos once in a while [here](https://www.youtube.com/c/AndrewKeepCoding).

Comment: Thanks. I was already subscribed to you! Just need to find some time catch up on your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A WinUI `Window` is just an abstraction of each of the low-level window implementations used by supported (UWP and desktop) app models.

The "trick" is to handle the `Loaded` event of the window's root element. The default template includes a `Grid` root element. A "generic" solution could be implemented something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var root = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
    if (root != null)
        root.Loaded += async (s, e) => await DisplayDialog();

}

private async Task DisplayDialog()
{
    var dlg = new ContentDialog();
    dlg.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;
    dlg.Content = "Hello World";
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

Also tote that an `async` method, with the exception of event handlers, should return a `Task` or a `Task<T>` and be `awaited` by the caller.